# How to make momentjs not a global variable in Angularjs, if it is possible

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am confused when reading [Angularjs style guide Y240](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y240).

It talks about creating an Angular Constant for vendor libraries' global variables, so that we can inject vendor libraries that otherwise are globals.

My understanding is you have to do this:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
```

before loading angular.js and controllers and directives in app.js, and moment object is a global variable. How do you use the following code to make it a service, and it can be injected when needed?

Please correct me if I didn't see the full picture.

```
// constants.js

/* global toastr:false, moment:false */
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .constant('toastr', toastr)
        .constant('moment', moment);
})();
```

**My confusion:**
Above code should make global variable 'moment' not global. Is this correct? I think it is impossible. moment is still global variable.

Comment: I don't get the question, after you set toastr and moment as constants, they are available for your controllers/services to be injected, can you give more clarification about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Why not add `delete window.moment` after angular constant init?

Comment: Agree, I was confused by this as well. Can only assume it is a readability thing, including the dependency in the controller/service/etc being more desirable than defining lint exceptions

Answer (score 0):

To use a constant created that way in your AngularJS app:

```
//declare 'app.core' as a dependency
angular.module('myApp', ['app.core']);

//declare the constant in your injection list
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', 'moment',
    function($scope,moment) {
        //use moment as you would normally
        var now = moment();
}]);
```

**Update**

`moment` is still a global variable.

The reason for doing this from John Papa:

> Why?: Provides a way to inject vendor libraries that otherwise are globals. This improves code testability by allowing you to more easily know what the dependencies of your components are (avoids leaky abstractions). It also allows you to mock these dependencies, where it makes sense.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y240

Comment: If you don't inject 'moment', moment() still a global variable. Is this correct?

Comment: I thought after injection, the mement object will be no longer in global scope. The reason I think that way is because "...that otherwise are globals". So it is injected, not otherwise, and therefore not global. Do you think their wording is logically error? Or it is just my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe they only meant to load momentjs using

**requirejs**

or

**browserify**

So that when a lib is loaded, it is in a function(){} for local scope.